# How can I retrieve my Google search history?

Tags: information-retrieval, web-search

In the Google Web History interface I can see all the search queries I have used over the years, and the pages I visited for a particular query. Is there a way I can retrieve this history using a computer program? I couldn't find a Google API that does it. Do you know of a tool that can do this, or suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: Similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332913/help-on-google-web-history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an [RSS feed](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=54464).

**Update**: the link is now broken.

Comment: But I'm not able to subscribe to this feed. Both Google Reader and BottomFeeder don't seem to be able to find it.

Answer (score 5):

The RSS feed in the accepted answer above does not exist anymore.  Google does not provide an API that allows you retrieve Google searches, but it does allow you to download an archive of all past searches, via [google search history](https://history.google.com/history).  This download cannot be performed programmatically, as it saves the archive to the user's google drive.

A possible hacky workaround is using browser automation tools to scrape the history page, like [this repository does](https://github.com/atbentley/google-web-history).  Modifying this script would allow you to get the most recent searches.  I was able to use this for my project.

Comment: **Update**: recently, Google changed their history page to use angularJS, and the linked repository no longer works for scraping Google history.  It does still work for programmatically logging into the page, though.

Comment: Another possibility is using a chrome browser extension and the chrome history API.  The 'sync' feature of chrome would allow you to get searches from any chrome browser that you're signed into.