# Is it possible to get the last google search query made by the user through chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a functionality based on the user's google search query. I am not interested in any particular link visited by the user after the search, but just the query used by the user. Is there a way I can retrieve it?

Comment: Maybe webRequest or webNavigation API with url filter for all google domains?

Comment: May be, I can try that. But if there is a google API to explore the search queries, I was hoping it could give me queries done by the user through different devices too, not just where the extension is running.

Comment: @labyrinth No, [there isn't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29932656/934239).

Answer (score 0):

There are some suggestions

1. Find the last google search url in [history](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history)
2. Add a [contentscript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to google search page to record the search keyword.
3. Use [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) to listen the search request, then record the keyword.
4. Visit https://history.google.com/history I don't know if there is an api for this.

Comment: Any knowledge of if this answer is up to date?