# How to Fetch google history of an individual?

Tags: browser-history, google-search-api

How can i fetch Google's history of an individual through gmail api using JSP/JAVA code ,

this link provides our history

https://history.google.com/history/

Comment: this helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130484/how-can-i-retrieve-my-google-search-history

Comment: Do you mean history as in what the user has searched for in the Gmail Client, or a history of other actions, like deleted mails, new mails etc.?

Comment: Sir , i mean web history (googles)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know about general web history, but if you are interested in gmail history (deleted mail, new mail, moved mail, ...), you can check out the [history listing](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list).

Comment: @Tholle sir , can i include history as RSS feed in my website , as i am doing a project on web mining ,